# React Gallery Filter Not displaying all the work when refreshing

Tags: reactjs, filter

I am new to React and recently making a project filter gallery. I followed some tutorials online to make this and everythings worked as I want. But if I refresh the website, nothing is displayed on the 'all' section. I have to click on other section type buttons and then reclick 'all' so that all the work can be displayed there.

**Current**:
[The current website when the 'all' button is active after refreshing the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hmJi.jpg)

**Ideal**:
[what I want it to look like when refreshing the page - displaying all the work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAF35.jpg)

Below is my code:
**Project file
**

```
import Filter from './Filter';
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState([GalleryData]);
  const [activeButton, setActive] = useState('all');

  useEffect(()=>{
    setData(GalleryData);
    setFiltered(data);
  },[])  



  return (
    <section className='projects' id='projects'>
        <div className="project-container">
          <div className="heading-project">Projects</div>

          <div className="selection">
            <Filter data={data} setFiltered={setFiltered} activeButton={activeButton} setActive={setActive}/>
          </div>
```

**Filter File:
**

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'

export default function Filter({setActive, activeButton, setFiltered, data}) {

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(activeButton === 'all'){
          setFiltered(data);
          return;
        } 
        const filtered = data.filter((item)=>
          item.type.includes(activeButton)
        );
        setFiltered(filtered);
      },[activeButton]);

  return (
    <div className="filter-container">
        <div className={activeButton === 'all' ? "active" : "list"} onClick={()=> setActive('all')}>All</div>
        <div className={activeButton === 'UI/UX' ? "active" : "list"} onClick={()=> setActive('UI/UX')}>UI/UX</div>
        <div className={activeButton === 'Website' ? "active" : "list"} onClick={()=> setActive('Website')}>Website</div>
        <div className={activeButton === 'Coding' ? "active" : "list"} onClick={()=> setActive('Coding')}>Coding</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I am not sure why this issue exist as I follow exactly from this tutorial:
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nyg5Lpl6AiM&t=572s](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setData` is async. Which means that in your `useEffect` the value of `data` is still an empty array `[]`.

You can simply use the `GalleryData` as the initial value of the `data` state

```js
const [data, setData] = useState(GalleryData); // initial GalleryData
const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState(GalleryData); // removed the []
const [activeButton, setActive] = useState('all');

// useEffect(() => {
//  setData(GalleryData);
//  setFiltered(data);
// }, []);
```